# C++ Acquire/Release Ordering

Tags: c++, memory, atomic, lock-free

Let's say I have 1 counter starting at value 2, some non-atomic boolean variable and 4 threads.

```
//Initialization (happens before any thread execute).
std::atomic<int> count = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(2);
bool someBoolean = false;
```

Thread 1:

```
count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

Thread 2:

```
someBoolean = true;
count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

Thread 3:

```
while(count.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 0);
//Now, we're out of the while loop...
assert(someBoolean);
```

Thread 4:

```
while(std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire), 
      count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 0);
//Now, we're out of the while loop...
assert(someBoolean);
```

Is it possible that the assertions at Thread 3 or Thread 4 may fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread 4 may fire the assertion because you use the `load` operation and the memory fence in incorrect order. You have to `load` the `count` variable first, then place the memory acquire fence.
In general case you have to place a Release fence **before** writing to a synchronization flag and place an Acquire fence **after** reading it.

You can find the detailed explanation and examples of Acquire/Release memory fences in this post from the great Jeff Preshing's blog:
http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/

Thread 3 (and Thread 4 after fixing the function call order) will not fire an assertion because synchronize-with relationship between threads is established correctly.